# SVG Arc With Fill Not Responsive To Hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using D3.js wrapped with Datamaps.js to create a map showing airline routes between countries. So far I have been able to create the map, draw an arc in the form of an SVG, and add custom plugin functionality to allow it to be responsive when I hover over it with my mouse.

The only problem is that the hover functionality is triggered when I mouse over the inside of the arc as well as the border:

[When my cursor is where the arrow is, the hover bar is triggered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcFnc.png)

I'd like to modify this so that the hover bar is only triggered when I mouse of the actual arc. I assume this is a modification I have to make when instantiating the SVG, but if I could change it using Datamaps, that would be even better.

Please advise me on how this might be possible.

Comment: Check to assure the fill attribute for the arc is set to "none".

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this can be achieved through simple CSS by changing the pointer events associated with your arc SVG. Assuming your SVG path element has a class such as "datamaps-arc", adding the following lines of code to your CSS should fix the problem:

```
.datamaps-arc {
    pointer-events:visibleStroke;
}
```

Read more about how to manipulate pointer event targets for SVGs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).